# Running XAMPP on Mac - Security Concern

Tags: php, mysql, macos, security, xampp

I recently installed XAMPP server on my Mac to test some PHP code. However, i'm concerned that doing this makes me vulnerable to attacks. The server is running on my main computer which is connected to the internet through a secure network (only I know the wifi password and i'm the only person connected to it).

I ran 'XAMPP security' in terminal and changed the MySQL root password. In the XAMPP homepage under security, I have:

These XAMPP pages are accessible by network for everyone UNSECURE

The phpMyAdmin user pma has no longer no password SECURE

The MySQL user root has no longer no password SECURE

The FTP password for user daemon is still 'xampp' UNSECURE

is this setup completely secure to use? Is there anything I can do to make it more secure? i'm new to coding so know little about security measures/best practices but want to make sure my setup is as watertight as possible. If there is anything you suggest I do, please make the instructions on how to do so as detailed as possible in your reply, as there is language used in other posts that I am completely unfamiliar with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you did the items you indicated, it seems secure, however, i would add the following;

If you're the only one using it, then lock down the below.

> These XAMPP pages are accessible by network for everyone UNSECURE

Also, make sure the Mac firewall is on by going to system preferences -> firewall.

Finally, i would check the XAMPP webserver config files to make sure non localhost connections are set to "Require all denied" or "Require ip 123.123.123.0/24"

You can check out Apache docs if using Apache:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html

Answer (score -1):

Run this command in the terminal and it will walk you though it.

```
/opt/lampp/lampp security
```

P.S run it as root.

Comment: I'm running XAMPP not LAMPP. As I said in my question, I have already run XAMPP security.